# OpenpyXL - How to return BOTH the calculated and formula components of a cell for any given workbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

At work we use Excel docs to perform analyses on samples, and one worksheet in the workbook is the 'Top Sheet', where all the important parts of the data are collated into a nice table for reports. I've written an exhaustive python script which uses OpenPyXL to pull out all the necessary data so I can pull this data out of multiple files. All of this requires implementing the `data_only=True` flag upon opening the workbook.

HOWEVER - I now need to pull data from another part of the workbook, another sheet (not the top sheet), which is actually referenced in a formula on the 'Top Sheet'. I've achieved this clunkily by essentially making the script open the workbook twice - once to pull out all the top sheet data, and once to pull out the formula (actually a series of cell references).

`wb_value = load_workbook(os.path.join(root, fname), data_only=True)`

`wb_formula = load_workbook(os.path.join(root, fname))`

Is there any way in OpenPyXL to return the data AND the formula without reopening? This literally doubles the time required to perform the extraction loop, which as I alluded to above is part of a larger structure which loops over entire directories to find suitable .xlsx files.

Any help massively appreciated.

PS. I've read Charlie Clark's answer to que 23350581 so am not optimistic there is an easy solution, but hopefully someone can conceive a workaround.

PPS. I can't hardcode the cell references I want to pull out as they, over time, have changed and someone has hardcoded Excel to track the position (over multiple years).

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by modifying openpyxl's code. Note that I've made these changes on openpyxl 2.2.5 which is not the latest version. Therefore line numbers will probably be different for you.

This is a quick monkey patching and most probably not the best way of doing this but it should get you going.

*Note that these changes won't make openpyxl to re-calculate the values if you modify a formula (as Charlie Clark said in his answer). This will simply cause `load_workbook` to retrieve both the cells' values and formulas instead of the need to call it twice.*

**\openpyxl\cell\cell.py:**

line 84:

Add `'formula'` to `__slots__`:

```
 __slots__ =  (
        'column',
        'row',
        'coordinate',
        '_value',
        'formula',      
        'data_type',
        'parent',
        'xf_index',
        '_hyperlink_rel',
        '_comment')
```

line 111:
Change `Cell`'s `__init__` to accept `formula` arg with default argument `None`:

```
def __init__(self, worksheet, column, row, value=None, formula=None, fontId=0,
                 fillId=0, borderId=0, alignmentId=0, protectionId=0, numFmtId=0,
                 pivotButton=None, quotePrefix=None, xfId=None):
```

And initialize it in `__init__` body:

`self.formula = formula`

**\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py**

line 111:

We don't really care about `data_only` anymore, so change the line from `if formula is not None and not self.data_only:` to `if formula is not None:`.

lines 113 - 116:

Change the following lines from

```
if formula.text:
    value = "=" + formula.text
else:
    value = "="
```

to

```
if formula.text:
    _formula = "=" + formula.text
else:
    _formula = "="
```

A few lines bellow these lines you should see

```
else:
    cell._value=value
    cell.data_type=data_type
```

Immediately below these lines add:

```
try:
    cell.formula = _formula
except UnboundLocalError:
    pass
```

That's it! let's test it:

I created a new xlsx file. Cell A1 has the formula `=1+1` and cell A2 has no formula, just the plain value of `2`.

```
wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

cell = sheet.cell(row=1, column=1)
print(cell.value)
print(cell.formula)

>> 2
>> =1+1

cell = sheet.cell(row=2, column=1)
print(cell.value)
print(cell.formula)

>> 2
>> None
```

Note that this will work regardless of the value of `data_only` that was passed to `open_workbook`.

Comment: Ok thanks for that DeepSpace; i'm reluctant to change the core library functionality as i have (literally hundreds of) other scripts calling on openpyxl and don't want to damage their functionality.

Comment: Also, do you know/can you think of a reason why this functionality - if it's as simple as the change you just made - isn't part of the core library?

Comment: @user2658194 I'm not quite sure actually.

Comment: hi @BAC83, i do have similar requirement. Were you able to find some workaround using openpyxl or some other library?