# read value of cell without data_only openpyxl python

Tags: python, openpyxl

Is there a way to read "calculated" value of a cell with openpyxl without opening the workbook with data_only = True?

I need both formula and value and i actually open the workbook twice...

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenpyXL - How to return BOTH the calculated and formula components of a cell for any given workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461237/openpyxl-how-to-return-both-the-calculated-and-formula-components-of-a-cell-fo)

Comment: I'll look into this... Seems interesting ! Thank you